# Prove equation using Bessel functions: $\frac{d}{dx}[xJ_n(x)J_{n+1}(x)]=x[J_n^{2}(x)-J_{n+1}^{2}(x)]$

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

The question is to prove that $$\frac{d}{dx}[xJ_n(x)J_{n+1}(x)]=x[J_n^{2}(x)-J_{n+1}^{2}(x)]$$

I have attempted using the product rule and the definition of Bessel but I just end up with a mess and no end in sight. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't try very hard using the chain rule.

Our answer is supposed to be in terms of $J_n(x)$ and $J_{n+1}(x)$, so write everything in terms of them (use the recurrence to write $J_{n+2}$ in terms of $J_{n+1}$ and $J_n$).
$$
J_n'(x) = \frac{n}{x} J_n(x) - J_{n+1}(x)
\tag{1}
$$

$$
J_{n+1}'(x) = J_n(x) - \frac{n+1}{x} J_{n+1}(x)
\tag{2}
$$

Chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\big[xJ_n(x)J_{n+1}(x)\big] =
J_n(x)J_{n+1}(x)
+xJ_n'(x)J_{n+1}(x)
+xJ_n(x)J_{n+1}'(x)
$$
Plug in $(1)$ and $(2)$.  Expand.

Comment: I have all of what you have written, which makes me happy, but I must have messed up somewhere or just given up too soon. I shall continue in this strain. Thank you.

Comment: I am stuck with 3 extra pieces after expanding and attempting to simplify.  Any advice on how to complete this? $$ J_{n+1}(x)[J_n(x)+nJ_n(x)-(n+1)]-xJ_{n+1}^{2}(x)+xJ_n^{2}$$

Comment: You made a mistake.  Every term must have two J's in it.  Your $(n+1)$ is therefore obviously wrong.  Perhaps it should have been $(n+1)J_n(x)$?

Comment: Ah, yep, thanks!